# Get folder from variable URL with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, path

I am developing a website, in **local** the URL looks like this:

```
{local ip}/{project name}/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}
```

but when it's **online**, the URL looks like this:

```
{domain}/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}
```

I need to make a jQuery AJAX request from one JS file called from

```
/{project division}/{private folder}/[index file]
```

That file is also called from

```
/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}
```

and

```
/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}/{other folders or files}/
```

So I need to get this part of URL

```
/{project division}/{private folder}/
```

for send that request from there to

```
/{project division}/{private folder}/ajax_call.js
```

How can I get that part of URL with JS?

Any other solution may be right.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid adding logic to your code that behaves differently in your dev and prod environments, if only for the reason that you won't be able to test the behavior of this code before it goes to prod.

Instead, do you have the option to configure the environment that runs the dev application?

If so, you could either use different ports or different (sub-)domains for different projects, e.g.:

- `{local ip}:3000/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}`
- `myproject.local/{project division}/{private folder}/{other folders or files}`

This allows you to simply use the absolute path for your service calls, the same way you would in prod.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean with "configure the environment that runs the dev application", could you please explain?

Comment: Well, `{local ip}` points to some web server, correct? Are you able to change this configuration?

Comment: `{local ip}` is my local IP running Apache server (XAMPP).